# Arranging $10$ people in $2$ lanes. Each lane has to have at least $2$ people.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways can $10$ people be arranged in two lanes, if each lane has to have at least two people?

What I did is use $\binom{n+r-1}{r}$ but that ignores the order in two lanes. Say one lane has $3$ people the other has $7$. This method fails to count the order in each lane.

Comment: Let the ten people be represented by the digits $0,1,2,\dots,9$.  Let the symbol $-$ denote where the left line ends and the right line begins.  How many ways can  you arrange $0,1,2,\dots,9,-$?  E.g. $03-12459876$ denotes the left line having person $0$ then $3$, while the right line has person $1$ followed by $2$ followed by... etc... How many ways if you ensure that there are at least two people in each line?  (*If you don't care which line is which, have you overcounted? how should you fix the count in that case?*)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: 6 balls to be arranged in two boxes such that a box may remain empty. Also, use $^{n+r-1}C_{n-1}$